# Things to Download for SSIS Package Developing in Visual Studio

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, ssis, business-intelligence

I want to start devleoping SSIS packages. I want to do this in Visual Studio Business Intelligence Integration Services developer.

It looks like Business intelligence is only available for Visual Studio 2013 at the latest. I currently have Visual Studio 2015 Community.

I have SQL Server 2014 and SQL server 2014 Management studio installed. In order to get SSIS packages will I have to install SQL Server data tools 2014?

After that will have I to install Visual Studio 2013 Community and Business Intelligence for Visual Studio 2013?

Is this all I need to create an SSIS Business Intelligence Project in Visual Studio?

Comment: Here are the options in the sql server download:

Comment: LocalDB (SqlLocalDB)
Express (SQLEXPR)
Express with Tools (SQLEXPRWT)
SQL Server Management Studio Express (SQLManagementStudio)
Express with Advanced Services (SQLEXPRADV)

Comment: Do I need express with tools or express with advanced services?

Answer (score 0):

SSDT comes wrapped with sql server editions but SSIS and SSAS aren't included with express editions (SSRS is). Developer edition might be appropriate for you.
The installation process will ask you what you want to install.I have never been able to get any of the editions to "work" with WIN home editions - professional or above, fine. When choosing a version of an edition simple rule of thumb is biggest for best for your architecture. For a presentation layer I would also get the excel add ins Power query and power pivot (if you have excel) and if you are thinking of getting to grips with dashboarding have a look at Power BI, Tableau, Qlikview all of which are free or have community editions.